# Yii url manager rules gets overwritten

Tags: php, regex, yii

The problem is my in my urlManager array.
I have

```
'user/<id:.*?>' => 'user/index'

'user/view/<id:.*?>' => 'user/view'
```

Where id is a string with an undefined length.

The second line is not working. Yii takes `/view/<id:.*?>` as Id strings and returns me an error with an undefined id. I don't want to manually split the url. I am sure there is a workaround but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of second line:

```
'user/view/<id:\d+>'=>'user/view'
```

OR

```
'user/view/<id:\w+>'=>'user/view'
```

Comment: What does the d+ or w+ stand for ?

Comment: d+ indicates that url has an "id" parameter with integer value and w+ stands for string value.